# SSL Check - Exchange Server responding with Self-Signed Cert

Tags: ssl, exchange, ssl-certificate, port, bindings

How do I set an Exchange server to respond to a Web Based SSL Certificate checks on a specific port number with the Public Cert?

If I do an SSL cert check on port 443 it gets the Public cert as the response. I have to allow a cloud based service send emails via our on-premise server but it uses a different port number to connect.

When I check against the SSL cert on that new port only the internal cert is found. I have bound the cert to the port on the Exchange server using the netsh http add sslcert command but it is still getting the internal cert as a response.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: This is not how certificates (usually) work. You'll need different or intermediate hostnames/domains/whatever

Comment: Hi - I have created a different host name and the cert is a wildcard cert on the server

Answer (score 0):

The default port for https is 443. May be we could try the IIS side.  The bindingInformation attribute contains the IP address, the port number and, optionally, the host header for the site. **The protocol attribute defines the protocol to use to communicate with the site.**